# Translating arrays from MATLAB to numpy

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I am defining an array of two's, with one's on either end.  In MATLAB this can be acheived by

```
x = [1 2*ones(1,3) 1]
```

In Python, however, numpy gives something quite different:

```
import numpy
numpy.array([[1],2*numpy.ones(3),[1]])
```

What is the most efficient way to perform this MATLAB command in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [33]: import numpy as np

In [34]: np.r_[1, 2*np.ones(3), 1]
Out[34]: array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.])
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `hstack`:

```
In [42]: np.hstack(([1], 2*np.ones(3), [1]))
Out[42]: array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.])
```

---

```
In [45]: %timeit np.r_[1, 2*np.ones(300), 1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.5 us per loop

In [46]: %timeit np.hstack(([1], 2*np.ones(300), [1]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.4 us per loop

In [48]: %timeit np.append([1],np.append(2*np.ones(300)[:],[1]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.2 us per loop
```

Thanks to DSM for pointing out that pre-allocating the right-sized array from the very beginning, can be much much faster than appending, using `r_` or `hstack` on smaller arrays:

```
In [49]: %timeit a = 2*np.ones(300+2); a[0] = 1; a[-1] = 1
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.79 us per loop

In [50]: %timeit a = np.empty(300+2); a.fill(2); a[0] = 1; a[-1] = 1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 us per loop
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu.  In the future, how should I go about trying to find routines like this?

Comment: It should be noted though that `r_` can be 4+ times slower than simply doing `2*ones(n+2)` and then patching the edges.  This won't be an issue unless it's in an inner loop, of course.

Comment: @DSM: Could you elaborate? Perhaps it depends on the version of numpy? I compared `r_` with `hstack` and got roughly comparable results.

Comment: @unutbu: I mean versus `a = 2*np.ones(3+2); a[0] = 1; a[-1] = 1;`, which for me (1.6.2) is consistently about 4 times faster.

Comment: @Doubt: Experience helps. There is no shortcut. I learned a lot of numpy functions by just going through tutorials (like the [numpy book](http://www.tramy.us/)), taking notes and writing example code snippets.  If memory serves, I think I first saw `r_` used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/190597).

Comment: @DMS: Oh, okay. I agree. It always pays to allocate the right-sized arrays from the very beginning.

Comment: @unutbu , for completeness, you may check CPU time also for `np.append([1],np.append(2*np.ones(300)[:],[1]))`

Comment: @Jan: Sure. I've added it above.

Comment: And then there's things like `a = np.empty(300+2); a.fill(2); a[0] = 1; a[-1] = 1` but these games don't usually repay the investment of time in them..

Comment: Thanks, DSM. I'll add it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.ones instead of just ones:

```
numpy.array([[1],2*numpy.ones(3),[1]])
```

Comment: That will give a very different object, not `array([1, 2, 2, 2, 1])` -- that's the OP's problem.  (If the OP's code worked, probably a `from numpy import *` happened, or the OP simply copied the code incorrectly.)

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed this.  Sorry for the confusion.